# UITableView memory issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm adding `UIView` in some Cells of my `UITableView`. I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and it seems that when I scroll up and down and up and down, the views are never removed from memory and it keeps adding new views in front of the already loaded views. It increases the memory forever and that's not the way it should be.

How to remove these `UIViews`'s from memory when not displayed ?

```
else if (indexPath.row == 0 && !isPremium) {
        // Google AdMob
        adCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:adCellId];
        if (adCell == nil) {
            adCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:adCellId];
        }

        AdMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        AdMobView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        AdMobView.rootViewController = self;
        AdMobView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        // load the ads
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"XXXXXXXXX", nil]; // COMMENT THIS LINE WHEN IN PROD

        // add gps
        if ([latitude length] > 2 && [longitude length] > 2) {
            [request setLocationWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue] accuracy:50]; // accuracy [m]
        }

        adCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0 green:149.0/255.0 blue: 24.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        if (!AdMobView.superview) {
            [AdMobView loadRequest:request];
        }
        AdMobView.tag = 3000;
        [adCell.contentView addSubview:AdMobView];

        [adCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        return adCell;
}
```

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without code, can you add your code?

Comment: Very good question. What's your evidence? How are you proving that the cells are not being reused? If you're right, it would be because your `identifier:` doesn't match the cell identifier.

Comment: By the way, here is some sample code that shows you how to track whether cells are being reused: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p411individualCells/ch21p710addCellSubviewsInStoryboard/RootViewController.m

Comment: I add a `UIImageView` with an alpha = 0.2. When I scroll up and down, it becomes darken, meaning it's adding once again a new image in front of the previous image.

Comment: Very good indeed: you've detected the problem and explained the issue very well. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cells are being reused but the views are still piling up, that would be because in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are adding the views *even to recycled cells that already have that view*. Thus the views keep increasing in number, piling up on top of each other in each cell, as you scroll up and down.

Thus (now that you've added some code) you are saying:

```
[adCell.contentView addSubview:AdMobView];
```

...for *every* cell, *unconditionally*. But if a cell is reused, it already has an AdMobView! You need to check for this so you add this subview only conditionally (and so too for any other subviews you add).

Comment: Look, for example, at this code of mine: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p403addCellSubviewsInCode/ch21p702overrideCellLayout/RootViewController.m I use a `tag` to mark the added subview, to ensure that I don't add it again and to configure it differently if it is already there in a reused cell.

Comment: And see further my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_adding_subviews_in_code

Comment: I added this: `if (adCell.contentView.tag != 3000) { [adCell.contentView addSubview:AdMobView]; adCell.contentView.tag = 3000; }` and it solved the issue. Great answer from @matt.

Comment: That's clever, and no law says you can't mark the cell by giving the content view a tag. But it is unduly inflexible. I would suggest that you imitate more closely what I do in the code I pointed you to - add the tag _to the AdMobView_ and ask the content view if it has any subview with that tag.